# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I complete the project on ASP.NET using VB.NET but I face error when running the project on other PC's with excel sheet .

Here is the error :-

Server Error in '/' Application.

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Project\WebSite8\test.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.

• The file is being used by another program.

• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Project\WebSite8\test.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.

• The file is being used by another program.

• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x800a03ec): Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Project\WebSite8\test.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.

• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.]
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad) +0
   _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Project\WebSite8\Default.aspx.vb:48
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +31
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3471

Below code is used

```
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
Dim raXL As Excel.Range

appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Project\WebSite8\test.xlsx") " The error coming from this line"
shXL = wbXl.ActiveSheet

With shXL.Range("A1", "X20")
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

shXL.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text

appXL.Visible = True
appXL.UserControl = True
raXL = Nothing
shXL = Nothing
wbXl = Nothing
appXL = Nothing
releaseObject(shXL)
releaseObject(wbXl)
releaseObject(appXL)


End If
```

Comment: do u have that excel file on other's computer on the same file location? No one is using this excel file at the time you accessing it?

Comment: no the file only placed on the server and no one have access on the file

Comment: I also grant access to administrator on IIS but still facing the same issue , i need solution for this issue please because the users cannot access the file on the server